# How to get the "reliability percentage" of a measurement

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, reliability

I need to get the amount of confidence I can have on a measurement (from 0 to 100 percent). In other words, I need to know how much reliable the data on a measurement is for me to trust its measurement.

I'm writing a software where the user taps a button at the beats of a song (a constant rate) and the song's Beats Per Minute (BPM) rate is measured by the software. I already made the software record those beats, calculate their average time (and BPM), standard deviation, standard error and coefficient of variation, which are indeed very useful information. However, I would like to have a way to simply inform the user about how much reliable are the recorded beats, so the software's measured average BPM really represents the song's true BPM and the user can stop tapping the button.

In theory, I think the more taps the software records and the less variation those taps have, the more confident the software should be that the measurement is close to the truth. But how confident and how close? That's where I'm needing help to calculate, to then display to the user.